# Pattern matching string and numbers inline using sed in bash

Tags: bash, sed

**Part 1:**

I have to vary values of multiple parameters. I have the *old values* that have to be changed, saved in *`$old_val`*, and the *new values* that take the place of the old ones in *`$new_val`*. *`$index`* is an array where different parameter names are saved. *`$rp` is the file* that has the lines to be changed e.g.,:

> ```
>  VMIN = 0.1,
>  ...
>  sn(1:3)   = 2, 2, 0,
>  sn(4:6)   = 4, 2, 2,
>  sn(7:9)   = 2, 2, 0,
>  sn(10:12) = 2, 2, 0,
>  ...
> ```

for this particular parameter `$sn`, an array of 12 values,

> `old_val=( 2 2 0 4 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 0 )`
>
> `new_val=( 1.82828 1.82828 0 3.65656 1.82828 1.82828 1.82828 1.82828 0 1.82828 1.82828 0 )`

I tried using `` `echo $old_val $new_val | sed -i "/$index/ s/$old_val/$new_val/" $rp` `` (here, `index=sn`) that resulted in

> ```
>   sn(1:3)   = 1.81.81.81.81.81.81.81.82828828828828828828828828, 2, 0,
>   sn(3.65656:6)   = 4, 1.81.81.81.81.81.81.81.82828828828828828828828828, 2,
>   sn(7:9)   = 1.81.81.81.81.81.81.81.82828828828828828828828828, 2, 0,
>   sn(10:11.81.81.81.81.81.81.81.82828828828828828828828828) = 2, 2, 0,
> ```

The 2's and 4's followed by *sn* are being changed, though not all. I did a bit of research about pattern matching and used

`` `echo $old_val $new_val | sed -i "/$index(\+\[0-9]\+\:[0-9]\+\)\}/ s/$old_val/$new_val/" $rp` ``, trying to match *sn(#:#)*

I am not very sure about the backslashes used for pattern matching as all the examples I saw were *find and replace* types. How can I correct this problem?

**Part 2:**

What will be the code to change parameters that are not followed by numbers in brackets in the same script? e.g., `VMIN = 0.1,`, here `index=VMIN` in $rp

Comment: There are some syntax errors in how you are handling arrays and using `sed`. First, use parentheses `()` instead of curly brackets `{}` to instantiate the array like `old_val=( 2 2 0 )`. When you reference an array, the variable should be in curly brackets like `echo ${old_val[0]}` with the square brackets containing the index. `${old_val[@]}` returns the whole list. 

On `sed` - you are going to need to align the position of the values in the original with the new values. It might be easier to reconstruct the new `rp` file with the new values than trying to replace values in the old file.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Sorry, it is my fault with `{ }` and `( )`, I stand corrected. 
I forgot to mention that `$rp` is a copy already and each time I try changing the `$new_val`, I make a copy of the original file and then alter in the newly made copy. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: `echo $old_val $new_val` would not output all array elements. `echo ${old_val[@]} ${new_val[@]}` would.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin
As in this way? 
`echo ${old_val[@]} ${new_val[@]} | sed -i "/$index/ s/$old_val/$new_val/" $rp`

I also have a previous `for` loop step where I call values of a specific parameter from a datamap `$values` and calculate the `$new_val` as a percentage (an array) .
`for old_val in $values; do`

`new_val=`\`echo $percentage | awk -v o=$old_val -v p=$percentage '{print o*(1+p)}'\`;

 `echo $old_val $new_val | sed -i "/$index/ s/$old_val/$new_val/" $rp`; 
`done`

This seems to work in calling the individual elements in `$old_val` or `$new_val` instead of using `{$` `[@]}`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, sorry, I am unable to add a code block or as _next line_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved and working by using exact pattern to match `(\b$old_val\b)` and refining the line to search on `($index.*=)`

`echo $old_val $new_val | sed -i "/$index.*=/ s|\b$old_val\b|$new_val|" $rp`